# Resolve sql permission denied

Tags: sql, postgresql, jupyter-notebook

How to resolve this issue in SQL

here is my code:

```
%%sql
CREATE TABLE temp_webextract AS
SELECT * FROM webextract
WHERE CAMIS IN (SELECT CAMIS FROM webextract
GROUP BY CAMIS, INSPDATE
HAVING count(score) != 0);
```

Here is the error:

```
 * postgresql://docker:***@nycinspection.tditrain.com:5433/NYCinspection
(psycopg2.errors.InsufficientPrivilege) permission denied for schema public

[SQL: CREATE TABLE temp_webextract AS
SELECT * FROM webextract
WHERE CAMIS IN (SELECT CAMIS FROM webextract
GROUP BY CAMIS, INSPDATE
HAVING count(score) != 0);]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/13/f405)
```

Can someone tell me how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You need to [grant](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-grant.html) that user [`create` permission](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-priv.html) on the public schema.

See [Introduction to PostgreSQL GRANT statement](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-administration/postgresql-grant/).

If you only intend to use that table for a single connection, and once you disconnect it will automatically be deleted, you probably want to [make a temporary table](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-tutorial/postgresql-temporary-table/) instead. `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_webextract AS ...`, in which case you need the `temporary` permission.